# Export geography field from SQL for use in GIS

Tags: qgis, sql, well-known-text, geography-data-type

I currently have a table in SQL server management studio (2012) with a geography column.

[image]

It definitely has valid spatial data, as I can view it in SSMS:
[image]

What I want is to export the data as a flatfile csv, so that I can load it into GIS software, specifically QGIS. I tried exporting as csv and loading the csv into QGIS, selecting the geography column as WKT, however QGIS did not recognise it. Is it possible to convert whatever format SQL stores Geography information into WKT?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use STAsText:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933977.aspx

So you could create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE wkt_export as SELECT *, RoadGeometry.STASText() as WKT FROM table_name;
```

Then export it and use the WKT field to load as a csv file to QGIS.

You could also try connecting directly to the server:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, It's returning "STAsText is not a recognized built-in function name" for me. The documentation says it should work for SQL 2012 though.

Comment: try: RoadGeometry.STAsText()

Comment: Updated answer. I should have actually read the docs instead of assuming it worked the same as PostGIS.